# How to add "floating label" for md-datepicker in angular material design?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Please refer to this [demo of input fields in angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/input). My problem is that while most fields like input passwords have "floating" labels the date input does not show anything, especially when the placeholder is hidden (because the date is pre-filled).

This makes the form very confusing, since there is no prompt on what the date dropdown represents on the form (and what the user is supposed to do).

**How can I add a floating label similar to input fields to the md-datepicker?** To make the form filling  more obvious and also give my forms a consistent look?

[image: angular material datepicker label]

Comment: Also can you please take a look at this form? The fields are just all over the place even though I copied most of the code  from the angular material demos: http://codepen.io/superasn/pen/VaJdqz (the widths are inconsistent, the verified checkbox looks funny)

Comment: I believe they have fixed it in current master so it should be available in the next release (current release 1.1.0-rc.5). Issue https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4233

Comment: This can only be done in Angular Material version 1.1.2 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a bit of messing around with css, I finally figured out the following solution:

CSS:

```
.date-picker-row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 60px;
}

.date-picker-row label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 50px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176);
    font-size: 12px;
}

.date-picker-row .md-datepicker-input-container {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <div flex-gt-sm class="date-picker-row">
        <label for="email" translate>Signup date</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.created_at" md-placeholder="Signup date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div flex-gt-sm class="date-picker-row">
        <label for="email" translate>Last update</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.updated_at" md-placeholder="Update date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the use of    md-datepicker-input-container    class in your example. Also why the for="email"?
I had to edit this a little to look closer to correct for me
(i.e.)
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176);
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

Comment: You are only simulating the behavior of the floating label, I think the answer of OHG_Techtips is the best one.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an input container:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Last update</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="user.updated_at"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Confirmed, this is nowadays the official way to do it. Just make sure you remove the `md-placeholder` value in the `md-datepicker` element.

Comment: This can only be done in Angular Material version 1.1.2 and later.