# How to add floating label on top of angular dart material dropdown select

Tags: angular, dart, material-design, angular-dart

Some of the **Angular-dart material** components come with a floating label which sits on top of the input element.

[image: input with label]

It is enabled by e.g. the following syntax:

```
<material-input type="number" floatingLabel label="Label text"></material-input>
```

I now would want the same for a material-dropdown-select but it seems it does not provide this feature. So the question is, how would I implement this best?

[image: dropdown without label]

Comment: This is a similar solution for angular js which I like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347018/how-to-add-floating-label-for-md-datepicker-in-angular-material-design

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following css code now:

```
.dropdown_with_label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.dropdown_with_label > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and the html looks like this

```
<div class="dropdown_with_label">
    <span>Title</span>
    <material-dropdown-select [buttonText]="foo"
        <div header>
            <material-select-searchbox
                label="Search..."
                [filterable]="bar">
            </material-select-searchbox>
        </div>
    </material-dropdown-select>
</div>
```